# Insert div in header PHP for specific page

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to insert a `div` in the header of my WordPress home page. So far, I've done it with little trouble, however I would only like this to feature on my home page which has `page-id-8`.

How would I do this. So far I can see it is a PHP if statment, but I have no idea how to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example

```
 if ( is_page(8) ) {
      echo'<div class="test">your content</div>';
     }
```

Comment: I tried putting that in the head of the document and just outside. I added a class to the div with width and height properties but nothing shows up.

Answer (score 0):

On the template you could use a variety of methods depending on how you wish to check the page.

If you need to find the home page (if you selected a page to be a static homepage) you can use the `is_front_page()` function.

```
if( is_front_page() ) {
    echo '<div id="test"></div>";
}
```

You can also use the `is_page()` function which takes in one argument. This argument could be an id, page title or page slug.

Here is an example:

```
if ( is_page(8) || is_page('Home Page') || is_page('home-page') ) {
    // do something specific to the home page
    echo '<div id="test"></div>';
}
```

If you want to apply this div on a specific layout or template you can use the `is_page_template()` function.

```
if( is_page_template('one-column-template.php') ) {
    // do something on all pages using the one-column-template.php template
    echo '<div id="test"></div>';
}
```

Comment: I just tried 

      <?php if ( is_page(8) ) {
       // do something specific to the home page
       <div class="test"></div>
       }

But now my screen just goes white... I'm so bad at php

Comment: did you echo the div? or at least place the html not inside php blocks?

Comment: from what you showed me, you just added the div at the end of the php comment so that wouldn't show anything. Comments aren't printed to the screen at all. I updated my answer to show the echo statement